# How to call a golang API(clusterIP svc) from angular(clusterIP svc) in k8s with ingress present?

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

*go version: 1.17*
*ng version: 9*

This project consists of a backend svc and deployment, frontend svc and deployment,
ingress

**Backend service:**

```
service/fiber-service   ClusterIP   10.105.244.88   <none>        3000/TCP   43m
```

**Ingress File:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-lite-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"

spec:
  rules:
    - host: lite.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: fiber-service
                port:
                  number: 3000 # service port
          - path: /?(.*) #need to check order
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: forms-service
                port:
                  number: 80 # service port
```

*Currently I am using HTTPClient and doing*

```
 testUrl(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(url)
  }
```

*Above code is from my frontend and it is called on a button click event*

Now, After tunnelling, I am able to access frontend when I visit http://lite.com
and I can make API calls by requesting on http://lite.com/api/v1 or something

**What I am trying to achieve is call the backend API via service name**
eg: **fiber-service:3000/api/v1**  as url to the above function
*Basically clusterIP to clusterIP service without involving Ingress*

Is this possible or does ingress interfere?
What will be the performance difference? (since this is an internal communication)

Comment: Yes, it's possible, they live in the same namespace, right?

Comment: yes, default namespace

Comment: Not possible, as the frontend code is being run on the clients computer, and not on your server.

Comment: @ThijsvanderHeijden But isn't everything inside the cluster within the same namespace, So access from one pod/service to another should be possible. no?

Comment: @Hackerman sorry, forgot to tag

Comment: frontend code is run in the browser of the person viewing your page.

Comment: ^^^ Your frontend code runs in the browser of the user using your web-app. If you try to make a request to a backend service, the users computer won't know where to route that request, as there is no DNS entry for that host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is not possible to do this especially when one's frontend has **client side rendering**

So, the problem is when user visits the webpage, it is rendered on the client's system. Hence, we are unable to find the `fiber-service:3000/api/v1`  so, it has to be called via ingress i.e. `http://lite.com/api/v1`

If it was server side rendering, then it would have been possible to call the service.